# Sorting strings with numbers in Bash

Tags: bash, sorting, alphanumeric

I've often wanted to sort strings with numbers in them so that, when sorting e.g.  `abc_2, abc_1, abc_10` the result is `abc_1, abc_2, abc_10`. Every sort mechanism I've seen sorts as `abc_1, abc_10, abc_2`, that is character by character from the left.

Is there any efficient way to sort to get the result I want? The idea of looking at every character, determining if it's a numeral, building a substring out of subsequent numerals and sorting on that as a number is too appalling to contemplate in `bash`.

Has no bearded *nix guru implemented an alternative version of `sort` with a `--sensible_numerical` option?

Comment: Is your prefix always the same?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Execute this

```
sort -t _ -k 2 -g data.file
```

- -t separator
- -k key/column
- -g general numeric sort

Comment: He need to sort by number - it is second field: `printf "abc_2\nabc_1\nabc_10\n" | sort -t _ -k 2 -g`

Comment: @RomanNewaza, Thanks! You know, zero is also a number. :-)

Comment: This is not zero based. Look at the man page.

Answer (score 56):

I think this is a GNU extension to `sort`, but you're looking for the `--version-sort` (or `-V`) option:

```
$ printf "prefix%d\n" $(seq 10 -3 1)
prefix10
prefix7
prefix4
prefix1

$ printf "prefix%d\n" $(seq 10 -3 1) | sort
prefix1
prefix10
prefix4
prefix7

$ printf "prefix%d\n" $(seq 10 -3 1) | sort --version-sort
prefix1
prefix4
prefix7
prefix10
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html

Comment: alas, this option has not yet been implemented on the aged version of sort avilable on the geriatric version of RHEL I'm developing on.

Comment: "sort -V" worked well for me.

Comment: "sort -V" worked also for me as well, which version of RHEL are you using?

Comment: this is exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 47):

You can sort using **version-sort**
Just pass the following arg
`-V` or `--version-sort`

```
# without (ersion-sort)
$ cat a.txt
abc_1
abc_4
abc_2
abc_10
abc_5

# with (version-sort)
$ sort -V a.txt
abc_1
abc_2
abc_4
abc_5
abc_10
```