# Rename files that are beginning with a number to two digits

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, file-rename

I have a couple of folders that are audiobooks. The files are numbered and I want to convert them to one file. 
I used the following script to convert them:

```
    #!/bin/bash 
    if [ ! -d mp3 ]; then
    mkdir -p mp3;
    fi;
    for f in ./*.flac; do echo "file '$f'" >> mylist.txt; done
    ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -b:a 320k mp3/title.mp3
    [ -e mylist.txt ] && rm mylist.txt
```

My problem is that I have to rename the first ten files because they are not in the right order. The files are named 1 - Title, 2 - Title, 3 - Title and so on. To get the right order I have to rename them to 01 - Title, 02 - Title, ..., 09 - Title.
How can I do that with a bash script ? Furthermore it would be nice, if the playlist.m3u file would be changed accordingly.

Thanks for your help.

@Cyrus posted the right Link to solve my problem.
The solved script ist:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d mp3 ]; then
mkdir -p mp3;
fi;
for f in ./*.flac; do echo "file '$f'" >> mylist2.txt; done
sort -V mylist2.txt >> mylist.txt
rm mylist2.txt
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -b:a 320k mp3/title.mp3
[ -e mylist.txt ] && rm mylist.txt
```

Comment: This might help: [Sorting strings with numbers in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17061948/3776858)

Comment: Thank you, I changed the script 'for f in ./*.flac; do echo "file '$f'" >> mylist2.txt; done
sort -V mylist2.txt >> mylist.txt
rm mylist2.txt'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sort -n` for this.  I did this:

```
~/SO $ l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    0 Sep  9 14:49 12 - Title
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    0 Sep  9 14:49 1 - Title
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    0 Sep  9 14:49 22 - Title
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    0 Sep  9 14:49 2 - Title

~/SO $ ls | sort -n
1 - Title
2 - Title
12 - Title
22 - Title
```

just to show you I did not "cheat", here are the aliases:

```
alias l='ls -lp'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Hence you can use:

```
ls | sort -n | while read file
do
    echo $file
done
```

the echo here is just to show that the order of files processed does respect the numerical values.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used sort -n to solve my problem.

Comment: It is important to note that this variant only works with file names that do not contain spaces or line breaks.

Comment: Nope, I did it with file names that contain spaces.

Comment: @Flavorum1: if it solves your problem, you can accept the answer with the ckeck mark on the left of the answer :-)

Comment: @Nic3500: Please test your while read loop with your files.

Comment: I did twice.  Before I posted, after you posted the comment. I did this: `touch "1 - title";touch "2 - title";touch "12 - title"; ls | sort -n | while read file; do echo "BEFORE${file}AFTER"; done` and I get the files sorted like the OP wanted.  Bash v4.3.48 on Mint 18.  The "BEFORE" and "AFTER" are just to make sure I did not add anything, or skip lines.

Comment: @cyrus: you can post the link to your solution as an answer. **Flavorum1**: you can accept cyrus' version instead of mine, once it is posted.

Comment: @Nic3500: It's all right, sorry, I made a big mistake testing.

Comment: @cyrus posted a comment, therefore I cannot mark it as a solution. Both solutions seems to be working.

Comment: The working solution of @Nic3500 is: 'ls | sort -n | while read file do if [[ $file == *.flac ]]; then echo "file '$file'" >> mylist2.txt; fi; done'