# sort does not work with -h with text file

Tags: shell, gnu-sort

In my OS, I can find

> -h, --human-numeric-sort
>             compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)

And I have a file aaa.txt:

```
2M
5904K
1G
```

Then I type

```
sort -h aaa.txt
```

The output is

```
5904K
2M
1G
```

It's wrong. It should be

```
2M
5904K
1G
```

Questions:

1. Why does sort -h not work? The result is wrong even in lexicographically order perspective. How to sort the aaa.txt file in  human readable numbers.
2. Or it can work only  with `du -h`? But [the most vostes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061948/sorting-strings-with-numbers-in-bash) seems can work with `awk`.
3. With `du -h`, `sort` does [not](https://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size) need to specify which field, like `sort -k1h,1` ? Why? What would happend if the memory size is not in the first field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does sort -h not work?

Below is a comment from [GNU `sort`'s source code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/sort.c?id=ae034822c535fa5#n1765).

```
/* Compare numbers ending in units with SI xor IEC prefixes
       <none/unknown> < K/k < M < G < T < P < E < Z < Y
   Assume that numbers are properly abbreviated.
   i.e. input will never have both 6000K and 5M.  */
```

It's not mentioned in the man page, but `-h` is not supposed to work with your input.

> How to sort the aaa.txt file in human readable numbers.

You can use [`numfmt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html) to perform a [*Schwartzian transform*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) as shown below.

```
$ numfmt --from=auto < aaa.txt | paste - aaa.txt | sort -n | cut -f2
2M
5904K
1G
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you answer the 3rd quetition:  do not neeed to specify field to sort?

Comment: I have this question because `If no key fields are specified, sort uses a default key of the entire line.`, [gnu manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html). So, `-h` will take the first field default, not the entire line. Is it right?

Comment: can you help to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066148/sort-the-entire-line-contains-blank)?