# sort the entire line contains blank?

Tags: shell, gnu-sort

There are 3 lines in aaa.txt. The first line contains space(ASCII 32), the second line contains tab(ASCII 9), the third line starts with space.

```
2 3
2       4
 2 5
```

Then type `sort aaa.txt`.  [GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) said **If no key fields are specified, sort uses a default key of the entire line.** Because tab is less than space, so the right answer should be

```
 2 5
2       4
2 3
```

But my bash shell got

```
2 3
2       4
 2 5
```

Questions:

1. Why the actual result is different from theory result? Does the separator not participate in sorting?
2. Blank is the default separator. So space and tab are separator in the same time? `sort -k2,2 aaa.txt` should get the theoretical  output below because `3 < 4 < 5`?

   ```
   2 3
   2       4
    2 5
   ```

Comment: I think perhaps the documentation you quoted intends to convey that if no key is given, `sort` forms an 'imaginary' key, i.e. set of fields, covering the entire line, i.e. all fields in a line; this would then act like a 'real' key would, i.e. ignore the separator for the purposes of sorting.

Comment: in manual: "By default, fields are separated by the empty string between a non-blank character and a blank character.By default a blank is a space or a tab...". So it doesn't distinguish by default.